# Oracle select column with special name

Tags: database, oracle, view

I have a view containg a column named "Started At". How do i select this in a SELECT statement ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT "Started At"
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can break the Oracle Database schema object name rules (no reserved words, start with A-Z, length 30 char, etc..) by enclosing the name within double quotes. To later access the object you MUST enclose the name by double quotes.

To the point:

```
me@XE> create table t ("x" int);

Table created.

me@XE> select x from t;

select x from t
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_X'


me@XE> select "x" from t;

no rows selected

me@XE> create view v as select * from t;

View created.

me@XE> select x from v;

select x from v
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_X'


me@XE> select "x" from v;

no rows selected

me@XE>
```